# Выделить биты из числа

Tags: c++, c

Допустим, есть переменная 64 бит:

```
unsigned long long a = 0x12345671FBC00045;
```

Как записать в другую 16-битную переменную `b` вторые 16 бит из переменой `a`, так чтобы получить в результате `0x5671`? Например:

```
unsigned short int b = 0x5671;
```

Как вообще выделять любое количество бит из переменной и записывать их в другую?

Answer (score 5):

```
b = (a & 0x0000FFFF00000000) >> 32;
```

ключевые слова для поиска - битовая маска и сдвиги. Почитать - [битовые операции](http://www.c-cpp.ru/books/bitovye-operatory).

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, очень помогли!!!

Comment: Или даже `(a >> 32)&0xFFFF` :)

Comment: в этом случае даже маску накладывать не нужно. Но на самом деле есть ещё десяток способов это все выделить.

Comment: Маска есть (`0xFFFF`) только накладывается она после сдвига.

Comment: Если использутете С++ можете посмотреть std::bitset

Answer (score 1):

Также можно использовать структуры `struct` и обединения `union`

```
struct _s 
{
  unsigned long long one:16; 
  unsigned long long two:16; 
  unsigned long long three:16; 
  unsigned long long four:16; 
}  __attribute__((packed));

union 
{
  unsigned long long m;
  struct _s s; 
}u;

int main(int argc,char * argv[])
{
 u.m = 0x12345671FBC00045;
 printf(" one   :> %#x\n",u.s.one);
 printf(" two   :> %#x\n",u.s.two);
 printf(" three :> %#x\n",u.s.three);
 printf(" four  :> %#x\n",u.s.four);
 return 0; 
}
```

Вывод :

> one   :> 0x45
>
> two   :> 0xfbc0
>
> three :> 0x5671
>
> four  :> 0x1234

Comment: эм... а тут точно нет UB с таким union?

Comment: @pavel есть `unspecified`, но не `undefined`. Т.к. расположение и упаковка битовых полей *`implementation-defined`*. А вот если заменить на `uint16_t`, то не будет. Ещё бы дерево на тройку поменять можно было бы :)

Answer (score 1):

Вы можете написать функцию, которая будет предоставлять маску по выделению любого количества смежных битов из числа, начиная с заданной позиции.

Ниже представлена демонстрационная программа, содержащая такую функцию

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

unsigned long long get_mask( size_t pos, size_t n )
{
    return ~( ~0ull << n ) << pos;
}   

int main() 
{
    unsigned long long a = 0x12345671FBC00045;
    unsigned short b;

    std::cout << std::hex << a << std::endl;

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < sizeof( a ); i += sizeof( b ) )
    {
        unsigned long long mask = get_mask( 8 * i, 8 * sizeof( b ) );

        b = ( a & mask ) >> 8 * i;

        std::cout << std::hex << b << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Вывод программы на консоль

```
12345671fbc00045
45
fbc0
5671
1234
```

Фактически, я - единственный, кто ответил на ваш вопрос: :)

> И вообще как выделять любое количество бит из переменной и записывать
>   их в другую?

Вы можете обобщить эту функцию для любого целочисленного типа, сделав ее шаблонный. Например,

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T>
T get_mask( size_t pos, size_t n )
{
    return ~( ~static_cast<typename std::make_unsigned<T>::type>( 0 ) << n ) << pos;
}   

int main() 
{
    unsigned long long a = 0x12345671FBC00045;
    unsigned short b;

    std::cout << std::hex << a << std::endl;

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < sizeof( a ); i += sizeof( b ) )
    {
        size_t pos = 8 * i;
        size_t n = 8 * sizeof( b );

        auto mask = get_mask<unsigned long long>( pos, n );

        b = ( a & mask ) >> pos;

        std::cout << "mask = " << std::hex << mask 
                  << ", value = " << std::hex << b << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Вывод программы на консоль будет

```
12345671fbc00045
mask = ffff, value = 45
mask = ffff0000, value = fbc0
mask = ffff00000000, value = 5671
mask = ffff000000000000, value = 1234
```

Answer (score 1):

Если переменная `b` уже имеет требуемую вами ширину (16 бит в данном случае), то  достаточно просто

```
b = a >> 32;
```